# How to add slots for Slot table such that there are no clash

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transaction

I have a Slot Table which has following fields :

```
   CREATE TABLE `Slot` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `starttime` datetime NOT NULL,
      `endtime` datetime NOT NULL,
      `assigned_To_Id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,

      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `appointment_assigned_to_id_foreign` (`assigned_To_Id`),
      CONSTRAINT `appointment_assigned_to_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`assigned_To_Id`) REFERENCES `Employee` (`id`),
    )
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now, the admins can add slot for a employee(assigned_To_Id) for a particular day by specifying the slots :
e.g. :

```
7 July Slots : 
11:45-12:00
12:00-13:00
and slot time = 15 mins (above time range will be divided in slot time intervals of 15 mins and assigned_To_Id = 1
```

Now before adding the slots we need to check if there are any clashes for the slots with existing data in db which are assigned to 1.

```
select count(*) from Slots
where 
(
    (starttime >= '2018-07-07 11:45:00' and  ('2018-07-07 11:59:59' between starttime and endtime))
     or
    (starttime Between '2018-07-07 11:45:00' and  '2018-07-07 11:59:59' and endtime <= '2018-07-07 11:59:59')
    or
    ('2018-07-07 11:45:00' Between starttime and endtime  and '2018-07-07 11:59:59' Between starttime and endtime)
)


or 
(
    (starttime >= '2018-07-07 12:00:00' and  ('2018-07-07 12:59:59' between starttime and endtime))
     or
    (starttime Between '2018-07-07 12:00:00' and  '2018-07-07 12:59:59' and endtime <= '2018-07-07 12:59:59')
    or
    ('2018-07-07 12:00:00' Between starttime and endtime  and '2018-07-07 12:59:59' Between starttime and endtime)
)
 and assigned_To_Id = 1
 so if there are 'n' slots --> check for each slot
```

Like for every time slot give by admin we have 3 conditions which we can use to check if there is any time clash or any existing slot

if the query returns a count of 0, that means we are good to add slots 
like divide 11:45-12:00 into slots of 15 mins and 12:00-13:00 also in slots of 15 mins.

My question is : How can I run this insert along with the count(*) query such that if two admins try to do similar thing only one of them succeeds.

```
Can we combine insert statement with condition ?
Is stored procedure a good idea for this one ?
```

Comment: *if two admins try to do similar thing only one of them succeeds* Lock (R/W) table. Then do your select/insert operations. Then unlock table. No another admin can lock the table and perform any operations on that table until you unlock it.

Comment: Can we do record level lock while using Insert and select query in one transaction

Comment: To do this, you can define your data model such that it is impossible to violate your rules.
The best way to do this is to use constraints on your table.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522026/how-do-i-add-a-check-constraint-to-a-table
Hopefully this article answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
check for no overlaps (or whatever)
INSERT (or update) new entry
COMMIT;
```

In InnoDB, locking the whole table is equivalent to locking every row.  Do I need to explain that that is a *lot* more costly than locking a single row?

Your `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` should pessimistically lock whatever rows you don't want mucked with until the end of the transaction.  Often it is a single row (lock one row ... update *that* row).  Or, it could involve locking several rows before deciding which row(s), if any, will actually be updated.

You should minimize the number of rows locked -- for speed of the `SELECT`, for speed of the `ROLLBACK`/`COMMIT`, and for minimizing interference with other queries.

Unless you have hundreds of `UPDATEs` happening per second, locking too many rows is not a big deal -- after all, your transaction *should* be designed to finished in only a few milliseconds, *not* the default `innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50 (seconds).

Comment: Thank you Rick.  Rick, so we write Select * from Slots where assigned_To_Id = 1 FOR UPDATE -> so this will take a record level lock preventing any new inserts where assigned_To_Id = 1?

Comment: We are using Nodejs with Bookshelf ORM --> is it a good idea to run at App layer or DB level ?
in case if App crashes the lock may never be released right ?

Comment: To prevent interfere we need to select all records - if no, records not selected are available for parallel selection... but if so, it's less expensive to lock whole table instead of lock all its records. Is it?

Comment: @Akina - I elaborated.