# Generate Slot Summaries(chunks of continuous slots) from the Slot table

Tags: mysql, datetime

We have a Slot table to store appointments. The app receives the date and multiple slots which are then divided into smaller slots of 15 mins interval.

```
 CREATE TABLE `Slot` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `starttime` datetime NOT NULL,
      `endtime` datetime NOT NULL,
      `assigned_To_Id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,

      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `appointment_assigned_to_id_foreign` (`assigned_To_Id`),
      CONSTRAINT `appointment_assigned_to_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`assigned_To_Id`) REFERENCES `Employee` (`id`),
    )
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now, the admins can add slot for a employee(assigned_To_Id) for a particular day by specifying the slots : e.g. :

```
7 July Slots : 
11:45-12:15
13:00-13:30
and slot time = 15 mins (above time range will be divided in slot time intervals of 15 mins and assigned_To_Id = 1
```

so Slots table will look like :

```
|id| startime            | endtime             | assigned_To_Id |
|1 | 2018-07-07 11:45:00 | 2018-07-07 12:00:00 |   1            | 
|2 | 2018-07-07 12:00:00 | 2018-07-07 12:15:00 |   1            | 
|3 | 2018-07-07 13:00:00 | 2018-07-07 13:15:00 |   1            | 
|4 | 2018-07-07 13:15:00 | 2018-07-07 13:30:00 |   1            |
```

Now, I need to summarise this in the front end :
like

```
    7 July Slots : 
    11:45-12:15
    13:00-13:30
```

Should I store these 2 high level slots in a different table or should I generate them from the Slots table ?
How can I go about writing a query to fetch  2 high level slots from the Slots table ?

Edit :  Slots in the table can be 'x' minutes (any value decided by the admin but it will remain fix for a given period of time).  When bigger slots are broken into smaller slots - we check that these smaller slots do not already exist in db (so no overlaps)  [link overlap question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211533/how-to-add-slots-for-slot-table-such-that-there-are-no-clash/211549#211549)

Requests will come in multiple of 'x' mins.

(so take big slots as inputs, divide them into smaller slots and when later the Vendor revisits the app - show the big slots that he defined). I need to know how to manage the big slots (store in separate table, store in same table with a flag or write a query on smaller slots to generate summarize slots)

Comment: *Should I store these 2 high level slots in a different table or should I generate them from the Slots table?* Both variants are possible. First variant contains the possibility of a logical contradiction. Second variant is more expencive. *a query to fetch 2 high level slots from the Slots table* If your MySQL is v.8+, use recursive CTE. If not, I recommend to use stored procedure, not query.

Comment: thanks @Akina. Can you elaborate on "First variant contains the possibility of a logical contradiction"

Comment: Nothing prevents contradiction of data in tables. Does the constraints which checks that the data in one tables matches the data on another table and vice versa exists? I think no...

Comment: Yes, it can get difficult to sync and maintain data consistency in both tables. How about if we use the same table and use a flag like "isLongInterval" and set it to true for big slots and false for 15 mins interval slot. How does this approach sound ?

Comment: Think to the direction of add all timeslots for a day (with NULL values in the `assigned_To_Id` field) if any timeslot of this day is created/inserted. Or maybe create a monthly timeslots pack beforehand. To compact the timeslots into timeperiods by continuous not-null values range is easy.

Comment: @Akina : sorry for the confusion but slots  in a day will be provided by clients so its difficult to create slots before hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80050/discussion-between-j10-and-akina).

Comment: Are the slots in the table only 15 minutes?  No overlaps?  Are the requests that come in for multiple of 15?  Etc -- Need more constraints spelled out.

Comment: @RickJames : No, slots in the table can be 'x' minutes (any value decided by the admin but it will remain fix for a given period of time).  When bigger slots are broken into smaller slots - we check that these smaller slots do not already exist in db (so no overlaps)  [link overlap question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211533/how-to-add-slots-for-slot-table-such-that-there-are-no-clash/211549#211549)

Requests will come in multiple of 'x' mins.